# How to properly pull a create-react-app repository and build (currently has error) - (Git)

Tags: javascript, git, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

So I've been developing on another server and now I want to put it on the live one.

What I've done on the live server is run the initial create react app

`create-react-app test`

then I go inside and git init it

```
cd test
git init
```

Then I set up the remote

`git remote add origin {link}`

from here on is where I'm kind of confused

I do a `git fetch remote origin` but am not sure what I should really do. A `git pull` gives me issues, where I need to add files, then commit them. I try a pull but it doesn't seem to change the contents.

However, when I do a `git checkout origin/redux` I get `* (detached from origin/redux)` when I `git branch`. The proper files *seem* to be there, but I'm not sure if this is safe.

Lastly, when I run `npm run build` I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in /var/www/html/test/node_modules/react-dom/lib
```

My package.json: http://pastebin.com/7UBDm2EV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About git pulling :**

If you are initialising git for this app why can't you just **git clone** that old app.

still If you want to do git init and pull old repo its fine.

you need to first add that old remote and get the old code by:

```
git pull old_remote to_ur_master
```

As it is new fresh repo it should-not show any conflicts on git status.

**About react error:**

It is due to old version of react loader.

Try updating it to the latest version:

```
$ npm install --save-dev react-hot-loader@latest
```

Comment: yeah... I should have just git cloned and npm installed it... I thought I needed to keep the node_modules dependencies and stuff >.>

Comment: @A.Lau I thought you have already installed it properly and it was just a  matter of cloning the repo.

Comment: no that was the problem. The other problem is probably caused by me having uninstalled react/react-dom and then reinstalled it because some of the peers were complaining about not being met. But I don't think I should touch the react stuff lol

Comment: @ changing/handling core react package is not a good approach

Comment: yeah I didn't realise. There were some packages, like redux, redux-router and stuff that were complaining about the version.